# Neo4j Cypher query - collect elements from 2 different variables to single list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following part of Cypher query:

```
MATCH (ch:Characteristic) WHERE id(ch) = {characteristicId} WITH ch OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)...
```

first of all I'm looking for `(ch:Characteristic)` by `characteristicId` and then applying required logic for this variable at the rest of my query.

my `Characteristic` can also have(or not) a child `Characteristic` nodes, like:

```
(ch:Characteristic)-[:CONTAINS]->(childCh)
```

Please help to extend my query in order to collect `ch` and `childCh` into a list of `Characteristic` thus I'll be able at the rest of my query to apply required logic to all `Characteristic` at this list.

**UPDATED - possible solution #2**

This is my current working query:

```
MATCH (chparent:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(chparent) = {characteristicId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (chparent)-[:CONTAINS*]->(chchild:Characteristic) 
WITH chparent, collect(distinct(chchild)) as childs 
WITH childs + chparent as nodes 
UNWIND nodes as ch 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(Decision) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[:CONTAINS]->(vE) OPTIONAL MATCH (vE)-[:CONTAINS]->(vEE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (cho)-[:CONTAINS]->(choE) OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[:CONTAINS]->(chE) 
DETACH DELETE choE, cho, ch, vEE, vE, v, chE
```

This is an attempt to simplify the query above:

```
MATCH (ch:Characteristic) 
WHERE (:Characteristic {id: {characteristicId}})-[:CONTAINS*]->(ch) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(Decision) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[:CONTAINS]->(vE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (vE)-[:CONTAINS]->(vEE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (cho)-[:CONTAINS]->(choE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[:CONTAINS]->(chE) 
DETACH DELETE choE, cho, ch, vEE, vE, v, chE
```

but this query doesn't delete required Characteristic nodes and my tests fail. What am I doing wrong at the last query ?

Comment: try 
WITH chparent + childs as ch 
UNWIND ch as nodes
OPTIONAL MATCH (nodes)<-[:SET_ON]....

Basically you get a list of nodes with `collect` and now you have to `UNWIND` the list, which is like a `.map` in JS, or like forEach, where you do a couple of optimal matches for every node in the list(collection).

Comment: Thank you ! Now it works as expected.

Comment: In your attempt to simplify the query, you're trying to match on the `id` property, but this is not the same as the internal neo4j id in the working query. You have to use the `id()` function to get or compare the internal neo4j ids.

Comment: Thanks, this way we are returning to the query like this one `MATCH (chparent)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(ch:Characteristic) WHERE id(chparent) = {characteristicId}` and it fails with an error that I have showed as a comment to your answer - `Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load NODE with id 827.` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this with apoc:

```
MATCH (chparent:Characteristic {characteristicId: <someid>})
OPTIONAL MATCH (chparent)-[:CONTAINS]->(chchild:Characteristic)
WITH apoc.coll.union(chparent,chchild) as distinctList
...
```

With pure cypher you can try something like this:

```
MATCH (chparent:Characteristic {characteristicId: <someid>})
OPTIONAL MATCH (chparent)-[:CONTAINS]->(chchild:Characteristic)
WITH chparent,collect(distinct(chchild)) as childs
WITH chparent + childs as list
....
```

Not really sure if you need distinct in collect, but I added just so you know you can do this to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. I never used apoc function before. I tried to execute the query on my Neo4j Embedded 3.1.3 and it failed with a following error: `Unknown function 'apoc.coll.union'`

Comment: well it does not come with Neo4j, you have to manually "install" it... there is a way to do this with cypher only, let me find it and update answer

Comment: I have also tried to add   `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j.procedure</groupId>
   <artifactId>apoc</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.3.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>` into my Maven pom.xml but it still doesn't work

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965481/how-to-configure-neo4j-embedded-to-run-apoc-procedures

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this easily by using a variable-length relationship match of `0..1`, as it will let you match on your root :Characteristic node and any of its children.

```
MATCH (chparent:Characteristic)-[:CONTAINS*0..1]->(ch:Characteristic)
WHERE id(chparent) = {characteristicId} 
// ch contains both the parent and children, no need for a list
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Will it return at least chparent node in case of no any children(ch)?

Comment: Yes, since if the `chparent` node exists, it will at least be able to match to itself.

Comment: Sorry for one more silly question but will this query return any descendant nodes of any depth or only direct children of chparent ?

Comment: I have changed the query to `MATCH (chparent)-[:CONTAINS*0..1]->(ch:Characteristic) WHERE id(chparent) = {characteristicId} OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)...` and it fails right now with `Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException: Node with id 5203 has been deleted in this transaction`

Comment: That's a new one. You don't have any `DETACH DELETEs` in your query before that? What version of Neo4j are you using, and are you querying through the browser or from some other system?

Comment: And as far as depth, `*0..1` is only the node itself or those immediately connected. You can specify a different upper bound if you want this at a deeper depth, or use `*0..` for no upper bound.

Comment: Thanks. I have only DETACH DELETE at the end of my query and I'm using Neo4j 3.1.3. Right now I'm testing it through SDN 4/OGM Neo4j Embedded from my tests.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details - current working query vs attempt to simplify it. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

A more simplified query.

```
MATCH (c:Characteristics) WHERE (:Characteristics {id: 123})-[:CONTAINS*0..1]->(c) return c;
```

Matches all Characteristics including the root node that (optionally) have incoming relationships of type CONTAINS from the node specified with id 123.

Comment: Thanks. I need to delete all Characteristics from parent to unlimited depth.. so I have adapted your approach: `MATCH (ch:Characteristic) WHERE (:Characteristic {id: {characteristicId}})-[:CONTAINS*]->(ch) OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)...` but right now it doesn't delete any `Characteristic`.. my test fails.

Comment: I realized that the id you are referring to is the neo4j node id, right? You have to use the id-function to match on that id. `MATCH (rn), (ch:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(rn) = {characteristicId} AND (rn)-[:CONTAINS*]->(ch) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)<-[:SET_ON]-(v:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(Decision) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[:CONTAINS]->(vE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (vE)-[:CONTAINS]->(vEE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (cho)-[:CONTAINS]->(choE) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[:CONTAINS]->(chE) 
DETACH DELETE choE, cho, ch, vEE, vE, v, chE`

Comment: Also, if you are using the neo4j internal id, make sure to change that and never use the internal id in your application. :)

Comment: Thanks. Your query works with no errors but my test fails because it delete all Characteristics except 1.. I think except the Parent Characteristic.. but I need to process and delete it also

Comment: Also, there is a property at Neo4j that prevents Neo4j  from internal ID reusing.. so looks like it is safe to use these ids with this property

Comment: this one https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.ids.reuse.types.override

Comment: Perhaps change [:CONTAINS*] to [:CONTAINS*0..1] to include the root node.

Comment: Thanks ! looks like this one is working [:CONTAINS*0..] for unlimited depth

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the children of Characteristic will also have the label **Characteristic**. Another assumption I made is, you need **characteristicId** which is defined by you, not the internal id defined by neo4J. **id(ch)** fetching the internal id instead of user defined ID. You might want to pass the characteristicId variable like I gave here.

```
MATCH (chparent:Characteristic {characteristicId: <someid>})
WITH chparent
OPTIONAL MATCH (chparent)-[:CONTAINS]->(chchild:Characteristic)
WITH chchild
<your operation>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to combine `chparent` and `chchild` into a single variable(list) in order to not work separately with two different variables?

Comment: check out `apoc.coll.union` for distinct list and `apoc.coll.unionAll`in the docs. https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions