# Correct method to setting up Neo4j APOC in embedded mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using embedded Neo4j, loading the library jars onto IntelliJ.
I want to try out the new features of APOC in Neo4j to run some graph algorithms.

I have the APOC jar downloaded and added to plugins folder as mentioned in the manual. What is the correct way to set up APOC to be used from Java?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this question here:
[How to configure Neo4j embedded to run apoc procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965481/how-to-configure-neo4j-embedded-to-run-apoc-procedures)

It is required that we manually register the procedures.